# Trigger a function immeditely after a user posted a comment

Tags: facebook, session

I want to trigger a function immidiately after a user posted a comment on a post. I want to read from session data, find the user ID and look his facebook_id if he/she has any. Then i will post the same comment on his/her Facebook page.

How can i immidiately know if a user has posted a comment?

How can i know which user is that?

How can i trigger a function after that?

Answer (score 2):

> How can i immidiately know if a user has posted a comment?

There is a hook called "**wp_insert_comment**", that is executed right after the comment is added. This actions passes 2 arguements first the comment id and the second is the comment.

> How can i know which user is that?

Well it depends on if the user is a registered subsriber of your blog. 
Use the hook "**wp_insert_comment**" in conjunction with the function "**[get_comment](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comment)**".

> How can i trigger a function after that?

It's just php so you can do whatever you want in your function.

This is just a help to solve your problem by your own. The hardest part will be to work on with the Facebook API.

Comment: Just wanted to share this link: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

Comment: I have solved the Facebook API part. Where will use the wp_insert_comment. Should i create a new PHP file? Which Wordrpess files should i include?

Comment: And after doing add_action() do i need to call do_action() or Wordpress automatically do that?

Comment: Also i can not use that with "get_comment". This function requires the "comment_id". What i need first is the "comment_id".

Comment: @Horttcore if i write add_action("wp_insert_comment", "get_comment_custom") function get_comment_costom("$comment_id"){ echo $comment_id; } Does it automatically get the comment_id and assign it to get_comment_custom as an argument?

Comment: Use `add_action( 'wp_insert_comment', 'get_comment_custom', 10, 2);` The id and comment are passed as arguements.